# Notification system based on LastUpdate

Tags: c#

Over the last few weeks I was tasked with developing a ticketing system specific to my companies needs. Alright, not a huge deal.. Now I am onto a little trickier subject that I just can't wrap my head around completely.

Notification System based on a tickets last update time.

Alright so as we all know in a ticketing system we have tickets, lots of them.. Each of our tickets have a ticket "state" such as "Waiting on Client", "Pending Shipment" etc. These states have different thresholds I.E: 60 minutes, 120 minutes..

Basically I have a server application that runs every two hours. It loops through all the open tickets in the system, checks their ticket state and threshold and if the LastUpdate time is outside of my threshold of 60 minutes then the system fires off a notification saying that this ticket hasn't been taken care of and someone needs to get on top of it. Alright great, so that means every two hours the system runs it will check the time, if the ticket does not comply with its threshold then a level 2 notification gets sent out. The same process applies for notification 3.

The problem with this scenario is that what happens when Friday rolls around? There may only be 3 tickets that have notifications that need to be sent by the close of business Friday. However when Monday rolls around and this system runs again, it is going to find every ticket out of compliance which means we will more than likely have over 100 tickets in peoples mailbox. This seems like such a common problem among any notification system that operates off a datetime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The best solution may depend on whether you want repeat notifications to be sent out, or if once is enough/

Comment: Sometimes the solution is to send a notification indicating that there _are_ outstanding tickets, but not per ticket.  It can contain brief summary information, e.g. number of tickets at various priority levels.  Then leave it to the recipient to check via your ticketing system for the details.  Another issue: A sampling interval of 2 hours allows for a ticket with a 60 minute window to be up to 3 hours old when it is picked up for notification.  Are you sure you shouldn't be checking more frequently?

Comment: Repeat notifications should not happen, I mean once a level 1 notification is sent then it shouldn't resend it unless it's resending it on a monday, that would be ok. @HABO I like the idea of having a summary of notifications and just listing off the tickets but that is more cumbersome than seeing a quick email notification of the specific ticket in the subject of the mail message.

Comment: @HABO However that suggestion doesn't resolve my particular issue. We are not looking for 100% precision on the notifications being sent. I just need a way to filter out non business hours and weekends :p

Comment: @jhartzell - It almost sounds from your comments like you want to only count the passage of "support minutes", i.e. a ticket submitted at 4:30 on Friday hasn't aged 60 minutes until 9:30 on Monday.  Weekend minutes don't count against thresholds.  Do holiday minutes?  Are some tickets covered by more than one shift of support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Now that I know it's a C# app..**

When your application is deciding whether or not to send a notification.. first, check if it is the weekend:

```
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
 // start sending notifications.
```

Or, you could do this:

```
if (TimeSpanElapsedToSendNotificationFor(thisItem)) {
    if (isWeekend()) {
        thisItem.LastUpdate.AddDays(2);
        persist(thisItem); // update the DB
        return;
    }
    // send notification here..
}
```

So, first check to see if the desired notification time has passed. If it has.. double check if it's the weekend.. if it is.. add 2 days to the LastUpdate property on this item then exit the function. If its a weekday, it will continue processing. Using this second method, your very first check will be false on the second run-through for all jobs unless they are added on the weekend.

PS: Why don't you just use a scheduled task and only run it during work hours?

Comment: We are using a scheduled task, that is exactly what this app is going to be; a scheduled task during business hours.. The problem is that if someone puts in a ticket at 4:30 on Friday and then Monday hits that ticket will be out of compliance which means it will send a notification, however this stands true to every ticket in the system, it is unlikely that we have a threshold that surpasses a day. So like I said before, Friday a ticket is updated, Monday rolls around and boom it sends out over 100 emails because every ticket at that point would be out of compliance.. Does this make sense?

Comment: I understand now.. but my second option is still in the running to help you. You can check for the day and time threshold and just add a few days to the current lastupdate time.. For example, if a ticket is added after 4pm on a Friday, then the LastUpdate becomes midday Monday. The idea is that you set the LastUpdate in the future if it's after a certain time on a Friday. When your app kicks in on Monday morning, the lastupdate time span is negative instead of positive.. so you would skip it.

Comment: Only tickets that are added after a threshold (e.g, Friday's at 4pm) have this, not every ticket. If you add 100 tickets between 4 and 4.30 on Friday then yes, you'll get spammed. Will that be the case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19459/discussion-between-simon-whitehead-and-jhartzell)